# Binding ng-repeat to empty array

Tags: angularjs

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

```
<input type="text" id="items" ng-model="items[0]" placeholder="item1">
<input type="text" id="items" ng-model="items[1]" placeholder="item2">
<input type="text" id="items" ng-model="items[2]" placeholder="item3">
<input type="text" id="items" ng-model="items[3]" placeholder="item4">
<input type="text" id="items" ng-model="items[4]" placeholder="item5">
```

I want to use `ng-repeat` but there are no items to iterate through because `items` is empty at first.

Comment: Why do you want to see them if they are empty? Maybe a little more context would be good.

Comment: You should initialize items[] in your controller or directive. Then you can ng-repeat over it.

Comment: you can create an array with 5 positions, but you need to put track by $index to allow the repeat to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **track by $index** to list a null-filled array:

see in [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/niwaluhebe/edit?html,js,output)

```
<div ng-repeat="item in c.list track by $index">
    <input type="text" id="items" ng-model="c.list[$index]" placeholder="item{{$index + 1}}">
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

`ng-repeat` won't iterate on an empty array. You could try settings items to an array of 5 empty objects, then update the objects later.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to set items in the controller like the following:

```
$scope.items = [null, null, null, null, null];
```

With this you will have an array to iterate over.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could actually initialize it differently in your controller, with the new keyword.

```
  $scope.items = new Array(5);
```